# Can I create a union type from an interface?

Tags: css, typescript

I want to be able to call the function getSvgPresentationAttribute with any valid CSS property name as cssStyleAttribute. But I haven't gotten it to work.

In my current code below I get the message `Type 'CSSStyleDeclaration' cannot be used as an index type.`.

```
export function getSvgPresentationAttribute(
    element: SVGElement,
    cssStyleAttribute: CSSStyleDeclaration,
    svgElementAttribute: string
  ): string | undefined {
    const cssStyleValue = element.style[cssStyleAttribute];
    if (cssStyleValue !== "") {
      return cssStyleValue;
    }

    return getSvgAttribute(element, svgElementAttribute);
  }
```

What can I do about this?

Here is what the interface I am using looks like.

```
interface CSSStyleDeclaration {
    alignContent: string;
    alignItems: string;
    alignSelf: string;
    alignmentBaseline: string;
    ...
}
```

Here is what I guess I would need as a type to make this code (or something similar) work.

```
type CSSStyleDeclaration =
    "alignContent" |
    "alignItems" |
    "alignSelf" |
    "alignmentBaseline";
    ...
}
```

I am open to any solution.

Comment: So, why not use the latter? Or do you want to automatically convert it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `keyof` operator to tell typescript that the parameter is any key of `CSSStyleDeclaration`.

```
export function getSvgPresentationAttribute(
    element: SVGElement,
    cssStyleAttribute: keyof CSSStyleDeclaration,
    svgElementAttribute: string
  ): string | undefined {
    const cssStyleValue = element.style[cssStyleAttribute];
    if (cssStyleValue !== "") {
      return cssStyleValue;
    }

    return getSvgAttribute(element, svgElementAttribute);
  }
```